# creating a span element in gwt on the fly

Tags: html, gwt

I need to create a span element inside div as soon as user starts typing in the div . I have set the contenteditable property of div as true but due to this the entered text is becoming part of the div and not the span  I tried using spanelement.focus() method but it did not solved my problem .

This is my sample code snippet :

```
Element div = DOM.createDiv();
div.setClassName("intelliTextField");
div.setId("intelliTextField");
div.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");

SpanElement span =div.appendChild(Document.get().createSpanElement());    
initialSpan.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
```

i am appending this span element to div as soon as user starts typing in the div.But the entered text is becoming part of the div and not the span.

Any Help ?

Comment: if answer is proper please accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you mean?

```
Element div = DOM.createDiv();
div.setClassName("intelliTextField");
div.setId("intelliTextField");
div.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");

Element spanElement = DOM.createSpan();
SpanElement mySpanElement = SpanElement.as(spanElement )
//do some job on SpanElement
DOM.appendChild(div, mySpanElement);
```

Of course you can omit creating SpanElement object and put directly spanElement into div via appendChild